Execution of synchronously submitted work items on different threads in iOS
Are synchronously dispatched work items executed always on the main thread in iOS independent of anything (whether they are dispatched to a concurrent, serial, global, or custom queue)?
I checked different cases and saw that synchronously dispatched work items are executed always on the main thread in iOS, However, it could be that there are some cases where synchronously dispatched work items are executed on a thread that is not the main thread as it could be that I didn't cover all cases in my experiments.
I tried the following cases:

Dispatch synchronously to a custom concurrent queue

Dispatch synchronously to a custom serial queue

Dispatch synchronously to the global queue



Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Unless, you dispatch the closure on the "main" queue, GCD can use any available thread. However, when you dispatch synchronously, GCD can make an optimisation to execute on the same thread where it has been called. Generally, one should not make any assumptions about the thread which ultimately will be used to execute the work item - with the exception of the DispatchQueue.main, which always executes on the main thread of the process.

You asked:

Are synchronously dispatched work items executed always on the main thread in iOS independent of anything (whether they are dispatched to a concurrent, serial, global, or custom queue)?

First, as a point of clarification, I assume you are referring exclusive to those items dispatched synchronously from the main thread. If you dispatch synchronously from some random background thread to some random queue (other than the main queue), then it will may run it on the current thread, not a thread associated with that other queue, and certainly not the main thread.
Second, as a performance optimization, when dispatching synchronously, it will attempt to use the current thread “whenever possible”. It does this to avoid an unnecessary context switch when the calling thread would be blocked by sync, anyway. As the documentation says (with emphasis added):

As a performance optimization, this function executes blocks on the current thread whenever possible, …

Now, I know you have attempted various renditions to manifest conditions where it does not run on the current thread. I have also unsuccessfully attempted to get it to run on the other thread. To add to your list of scenarios, I have also attempted this where the background queue was busy, where the background queue had a higher QoS, both with and without the enforceQoS option, where the background queue had some specific target queue, etc.
But our failures to manifest scenarios where this optimization does not take place does not mean that it never can never happen. There are undoubtedly edge-cases where it cannot safely perform this optimization. (I have seen cryptic references to the fact that it might opt out of this performance situation in high-contention scenarios, but I have not yet been able to manifest it, so I cannot comment further.)
Bottom line, enjoy the performance benefits of this optimization, as it appears that it almost always employs it, but never rely upon it. It would be imprudent to assume that this optimization will always take place given that Apple has explicitly warned us that it might not.

As an aside, there is one well-known exception to this performance optimization. Namely, if you are on a background thread and dispatch synchronously to the main thread, it will always run that dispatched code on the main thread, not the current thread. As the documentation goes on to say:

… with one exception: Blocks submitted to the main dispatch queue always run on the main thread.

I know this caveat does not apply in your situation, but I add this disclaimer for the sake of completeness.

A few final caveats:

We rarely dispatch synchronously from the main thread. The one common exception is when doing a very fast synchronization to eliminate data races. But, one should never synchronously dispatch anything slow from the main thread.
Other than simple synchronization patterns, the typical “dispatch to from main thread to another queue” is used to get work off the main thread. And in these scenarios, we would always dispatch asynchronously (as the whole point is to avoid blocking the current thread).

The fact that code dispatched synchronously from the main thread does or does not run on the main thread is somewhat immaterial. Either way, you are blocking the main thread and the thread upon which the dispatched code runs is not really relevant. Just do not write code that is dependent upon it running on the main thread: You have no such formal assurances.


